# How to display all group by information when condition exists?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a page that displays "file tags" for files uploaded on my system. Every file can have 0, 1 or more file tags associated with it.

I have successfully made a page that will display file names and their tags, such as:

```
File     Tag(s)
File#1   None
File#2   TAG1
File#3   TAG1, TAG2
```

This SQL query would help produce the data above:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`ftg_name` ORDER BY `ftg_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
  AS `x_file_tag_names` 
FROM `file` LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` ON `fileftg_file` = `file_id` 
LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON `ftg_id` = `fileftg_filetag` 
GROUP BY `fileftg_file` ORDER BY `file_created` DESC;
```

**Problem:**

I have just implemented filters on the top of the page. Filters that allow me to select between different file tags in the system. When someone selects a filter, I add a condition in the WHERE clause. Look at this query:

```
 SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`ftg_name` ORDER BY `ftg_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
   AS `x_file_tag_names` FROM `file` 
 LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` ON `fileftg_file` = `file_id` 
 LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON `ftg_id` = `fileftg_filetag` 
 WHERE `fileftg_filetag` = '1' 
 GROUP BY `fileftg_file` ORDER BY `file_created` DESC;
```

This produces this result on my page:

```
File     Tag(s)
File#1   None
File#2   TAG1
File#3   TAG1
```

The problem here is that I still want it to list `TAG1, TAG2` for `File#3`. But of course the WHERE condition is getting rid of the `TAG2`.
I'm wondering if there is a solution that would involve only changing the SELECT condition. I was attempting to create a solution that looked something like:

```
SELECT *, IF(ISNULL(`filetag_file`), 'None', 
  (//a subquery that gets all file tags associated with file in outer query))
```

Comment: Please don't use `SELECT *`.  Also, you're aware that, if you specify columns not `GROUP`ed, or in an aggregate, the actual values of the columns are undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this.  This is assuming there is a field called "file" in the "file" table.

```
SELECT  *, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(`ftg_name` ORDER BY `ftg_name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `x_file_tag_names` 

FROM    `file` 
        LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` ON `fileftg_file` = `file_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON `ftg_id` = `fileftg_filetag` 

WHERE file.file_id in (SELECT file_id 
                       FROM   `file` 
                              LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` ON `fileftg_file` = `file_id` 
                              LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON `ftg_id` = `fileftg_filetag` 
                       WHERE `fileftg_filetag` = '1')
```

GROUP BY `fileftg_file` ORDER BY `file_created` DESC;

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you think of any solutions that would involve just changing the SELECT part of the query rather than the WHERE part?

Comment: Tom - you _may_ be able to do the current outer query as the actual subquery for the `SELECT` list.  Unfortunately, I don't know this part of mySQL that well....

Answer (score 1):

One more ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63afe/7/0)):

```
select file,
       group_concat(ftg_name order by ftg_name separator ', ') as tag_names
from file
left join link_file_filetag on fileftg_file = file_id
left join filetag on ftg_id = fileftg_filetag
where exists (select *
              from link_file_filetag 
              where fileftg_filetag = 1
                    and fileftg_file = file_id)
group by fileftg_file
order by file_created desc;
```

Result:

```
FILE   TAG_NAMES  
File#2 TAG1  
File#3 TAG1, TAG2
```

Answer (score 0):

This would allow you to do the group_concat as part of the select statement.  I am guessing on which tables contain which fields since you did not use table prefixes in your joins.

```
SELECT  *, 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`ftg_name` ORDER BY `ftg_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
  AS `x_file_tag_names` 
         FROM `file` LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` ON `fileftg_file` = `file_id` 
                     LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON `ftg_id` = `fileftg_filetag`
         WHERE file_id = f.file_id
         GROUP BY `fileftg_file` ORDER BY `file_created` DESC) AS tags

FROM    `file` f
        LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` lff ON lff.`fileftg_file` = f.`file_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON ft.`ftg_id` = lff.`fileftg_filetag` 

WHERE   `fileftg_filetag` = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the answers, but after thinking about it, you might like this one best.  This way, any group with the appropriate tag will appear.  So no subquery would be needed.

```
 SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`ftg_name` ORDER BY `ftg_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
   AS `x_file_tag_names` FROM `file` 
 LEFT JOIN `link_file_filetag` ON `fileftg_file` = `file_id` 
 LEFT JOIN `filetag` ON `ftg_id` = `fileftg_filetag` 
 GROUP BY `fileftg_file` 
 HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN `fileftg_filetag` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
 ORDER BY `file_created` DESC;
```